# Is it semantic markup to put full screen background video tag inside header tag?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have to display full screen background video for my website. I'm very strict to write semantic html5 markup.

I need to know, where i should put video markup? Should it be inside `<header>` or `<main>`?

Method#1 - Inside `<header>`

```
<body>
        <header>
            <nav></nav>
            <div class="bg-video">
                <!-- Full screen background video -->
                <video class="bg-video-content" poster="video/fxb.jpg" autoplay loop muted>
                   <source src="video/fxb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                   <source src="video/fxb.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                   <source src="video/fxb.webm" type="video/webm">
               </video>
           </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <!-- Services -->
            <section class="services"></section>
        </main>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
```

Method#2 - Inside `<main>`

```
<body>
        <header>
            <nav></nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <!-- Home -->
            <section class="home">
                <div class="bg-video">
                     <!-- Full screen background video -->
                     <video class="bg-video-content" poster="video/fxb.jpg" autoplay loop muted>
                        <source src="video/fxb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="video/fxb.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                        <source src="video/fxb.webm" type="video/webm">
                    </video>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
```

I also want to place logo and nav inside `header`, so is it good practice to put `video` tag along with a heading and a button on top of it inside `header` or i should put `video` tag inside `main` area? Thanks

Comment: The page is about the video, so why not put video in `main`?

Comment: I want to display video just on home section with a heading and button on top of it, i do have other sections like services, about, work and etc.

Comment: Maybe do like `<header> nav > ul > li * 5 </header><main> section * 5 </main><footer></footer>`, and `video` in one of the section?

Comment: @NoobTW, So you mean, i should put video inside <main> tag?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest that.

Comment: Is this video content (like an article) or decoration (like a background image)?

Comment: Its the video file running on web page.